# S-Pen Button Click

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile-sdk

I am trying to create my first app which uses S-Pen. The problem is that at the online tutorial, Samsung has different classes and libraries than the libraries I have downloaded from their website.

The only thing I want, at the moment, to do is to get events (hover, s-pen's button clicked, etc).

Which S-Pen SDK do you use for development?

Comment: http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk/technical-docs/S-Pen-SDK-2-3-Tutorial

Comment: This is different from what I have downloaded. I found some listeners but I cannot find any listener for S-Pen's button.